# Jmeter ant html report questions

Tags: java, ant, jmeter

I'm working on integrating jmeter tests on CI and having one issue that wasn't able to solve by myself. I'm using ANT for executing jmeter project and generating html report at the end. The issue is related to the final html report - it contains a bunch of Iterations for each of the test(WS request). In my jmeter project I have set Thread properties - thread groups(users)=1, loop count =1, so I expect to have only one iteration per test(WS sampler)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrE2q.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not something connected with Ant as when Ant produces HTML report it basically does [XSLT Transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) of .jtl result file (which is basically XML) using some pre-defined templates, see [Visualizing JMeter .jtl Files Viewed as An .xsl Stylesheet](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/visualizing-jmeter-jtl-files-viewed-xsl-stylesheet) article for details.

My expectation is that you are getting all these "extra iterations" as each time you run a JMeter test the results are being **added** to the existing .jtl results file and you are getting historic results. The solution is to delete .jtl results file via [Delete Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) (or move it somewhere using [Move Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html)) when Ant job starts so you will be sure you always get "fresh" results